# Can different IDE share a same workspace?

Tags: eclipse, workspace, spring-tool-suite

I would like to use Eclipse and Spring Tool Suite at the same time using the same workspace.
Is there a way to do that?

PS: I've tried deleting .lock file in .metadata directory. But after I open Eclipse again, it's regenerated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that STS is based on Eclipse, I am not sure first why you would want to do that and then I do not think it is possible.

Comment: Eclipse locks the workspace because it is not safe to run two Eclipse instances on one workspace.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need this? Perhaps you can achieve it running only 1 IDE, by using active lists of projects, or something similar

Comment: @Grove Don't know if I really need to use two IDEs, but I'm running a Client on Eclipse and a Server on sts

Comment: You can run both client and server from the same IDE and switch between their assigned consoles, by clicking on the down arrow symbol next to the cosole button/icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. The workspace stores several piece of information that both IDEs require (e.g. the Eclipse file system model that stores the list of all projects).

There are two things you could do (if you really require to work with both components):

- Install every plug-in of one of your IDEs into the other (presumably it would be easier to install your Eclipse plug-ins into STS, but it very much depends on what you have installed). Then, if you need, you can open two windows (*Window* / *New Window* from the main menu), and then manage your stuff as needed.
- Maintain two installations with two different workspaces, that share a set of projects stored outside the workspace. However, I would not recommend this approach because

  1. You have to refresh the projects in the other workspace (where you were not editing)
  2. The automatic builders registered in both workspaces would execute much often, and even worse, they could be conflicting with each other.

If you only need to work with the same set of versioned projects in the Eclipse instances, then maybe it would be a better idea to create a [Team Project Set](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-cvs-project-set.htm) of your projects, and check them out into both workspaces, and share your changes through the version control system.